# How to get the attribute with Regex?

Tags: php, regex

the html code:

```
<a class="frame" title="lorem" rel="photo[pp_gal]" href="/img/big.png">
    <img alt="lorem" src="/img/small.png">
</a>
```

I can get 「/img/big.png」 like this:

```
$pattern = '/rel="photo\\[pp_gal\\]" href="(.*)">/';
```

but now I want to get 「/img/small.png」 with 'img' in the 'a tag'.
How to get that attribute value? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use DomDocument to parse HTML, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @miken32, you should not attempt to parse HTML with regex.

If you still need it, you can try this one

`<a.*>\s.*?<img.*?src="(.*)">`

- `<a.*>\s.*?<img.*?` searches for `img` tag inside `a` tag
- `src="(.*)"` captures the content of src attribute inside the capture
  group.

You can find the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/w96xLc/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's clear and easy understand.
About DomDocument, I will try. Thanks again.